# Is a way to define abs (lower abs)-slim guy

Tags: workout

I want to define my abs.I am slim guy and I want to define the lower abs.I eat plenty of vegetables,fruits etc,protein etc.I am doing workouts too.What would you tell me to do to define my lower abs.

Comment: I understand you have a lot of questions regarding fitness. However, many of the questions you ask are either of poor quality or have been asked many times before. I would suggest you take the tour and read the help pages about how to ask good questions. There is also a search function where you can research your questions as well.